# Daily javascript countdown shorten to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found this daily countdown timer and edited it a little but I find it a little long and learned that Jquery is a shorter notation of javascript but don't know anything about it.

My knowledge is not advanced enough to either shorten this or change it to jquery.

I use the `<body onload = "getSeconds()">` to start the daily countdown.

```
var reloadPage = false;
function getSeconds()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
    var midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),21,57,0); //midnight 0000 hrs
    //midnight - change time hh,mm,ss to whatever time required, e.g. 7,50,0 (0750)
    var ft = midnight.getTime() + 86400000; // add one day 86 400 000
    var diff = ft - time;
    diff = parseInt(diff/1000);
    if (diff > 86400) {diff = diff - 86400}
    startTimer (diff);
}

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs){
    timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
    ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000); 
    tick(); //to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeInSecs--;
    }
    else
    {
    clearInterval(ticker); //stop counting at zero
    if (secs == 0)
    {
        reloadPage = true;
        console.log("reset");
    };
    getSeconds();  //and start again if required
}

var hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
secs %= 3600;
var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
secs %= 60;

if(reloadPage)
{
    var result = "Please reload page for daily reset."
}
else
{
    var result = ((hours <= 0 ) ? "" : hours + " hours ") + ( (mins <= 0) ? "" : mins + " minutes " ) + ( (mins <= 0) ? " < 1 minute " : "" );
}
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Daily reset: " + result;
}
```

Comment: jQuery is **not** a shorter notation of JS! It's a huge library (several thousand lines of code), that levels many differences between different (mostly older) browsers and provides you with some additional functionality/sugar.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code "changed to jQuery"

```
var reloadPage = false;
function getSeconds()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
    var midnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),21,57,0); //midnight 0000 hrs
    //midnight - change time hh,mm,ss to whatever time required, e.g. 7,50,0 (0750)
    var ft = midnight.getTime() + 86400000; // add one day 86 400 000
    var diff = ft - time;
    diff = parseInt(diff/1000);
    if (diff > 86400) {diff = diff - 86400}
    startTimer (diff);
}

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs){
    timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
    ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000); 
    tick(); //to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeInSecs--;
    }
    else
    {
    clearInterval(ticker); //stop counting at zero
    if (secs == 0)
    {
        reloadPage = true;
        console.log("reset");
    };
    getSeconds();  //and start again if required
}

var hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
secs %= 3600;
var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
secs %= 60;

if(reloadPage)
{
    var result = "Please reload page for daily reset."
}
else
{
    var result = ((hours <= 0 ) ? "" : hours + " hours ") + ( (mins <= 0) ? "" : mins + " minutes " ) + ( (mins <= 0) ? " < 1 minute " : "" );
}
$("#countdown").html("Daily reset: " + result);
}
```

saving 27 bytes ... I'm sure loading 86000+ bytes of jQuery library wont negate this saving at all

Comment: Well I already had jquery loaded in but I thought the code would be even shorter with jquery

Answer (score 1):

a shorter implementation, imo. simpler, and no need for jQuery (even if you've already loaded it)

```
//a few values that come in handy when dealing with timestamps
MILLISECOND = MILLISECONDS = 1;
SECOND = SECONDS = 1000*MILLISECONDS;
MINUTE = MINUTES = 60*SECONDS;
HOUR = HOURS = 60*MINUTES;
DAY = DAYS = 24*HOURS;
TIMEZONE_OFFSET = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * MINUTES;

var midnight = Date.now() + DAY - (Date.now() - TIMEZONE_OFFSET) % DAY;

function updateCountdown(){
    //an utility to fetch the parts (hours, mins, ...) of the time
    //and return a formated output
    function fetch(factor, postfix){
        var value = Math.floor(t/factor);
        t %= factor;    //beware: side-effect

        //format the value
        return value > 0? 
            value + (postfix == null? "": postfix): 
            "";
    }

    var t = midnight - Date.now(); //time till midnight

    var countdown = document.querySelector("#countdown");
    if(t <= 0){
        countdown.innerHTML = "Please reload page for daily reset.";
        location.reload();
    }else{
        countdown.innerHTML = [
            "Daily reset:",
            fetch(HOURS, " hours"),
            fetch(MINUTES, " minutes"),
            fetch(SECONDS, " seconds")
        ].join(" ");

        setTimeout(updateCountdown, 200);
    }
}

updateCountdown();
```

**Edit:**

> how would I change the time to be resetted at

the variable `midnight` holds the target-timestamp I am counting to: `t = midnight-Date.now()`

change the target timestamp.

```
//a utility that gives you the timestamp for today `00:00 AM` (in your local timezone)
function today(){
    var now = Date.now();
    return now - (now - TIMEZONE_OFFSET) % DAY;
}

console.log( new Date( today() ) ); //today 00:00:00 GMT+yourTimeZoneOffset
```

define a target timezone:

```
var midnight = today() + 1*DAY;
var target = today() + 20*HOURS + 45*MINUTES + 59*SECONDS;
//you see how these constants get handy ;)
```

and compute the time to that target:

```
var t = target - Date.now();
```

the rest is the same

Comment: It's working with less code, thank you but how would I change the time to be resetted at instead of midnight to test it?

Comment: I tried editing it but the page kept reseting when I changed it, can you add a full version of the edited code in a sort of drop down?